# Define a recursive function within a function in Go

Tags: function, recursion, go

I am trying to define a recursive function within another function in Go but I am struggling to get the right syntax. I am looking for something like this:

```
func Function1(n) int {
   a := 10
   Function2 := func(m int) int {
      if m <= a {
         return a
      }
      return Function2(m-1)
   }

   return Function2(n)
}
```

I'd like to keep Function2 inside the scope of Function1 as it is accessing some elements of its scope.

How can I do this in Go?

Many thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can't access `Function2` inside of it if it is in the line where you declare it. The reason is that you're not referring to a *function* but to a *variable* (whose type is a function) and it will be accessible only after the declaration.

Quoting from [Spec: Declarations and scope:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

> The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.

In your example `Function2` is a variable declaration, and the VarSpec is:

```
Function2 := func(m int) int {
    if m <= a {
        return a
    }
    return Function2(m-1)
}
```

And as the quote form the language spec describes, the variable identifier `Function2` will only be in scope after the declaration, so you can't refer to it inside the declaration itself. For details, see [Understanding variable scope in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503560/understanding-variable-scope-in-go/52506086#52506086).

Declare the `Function2` variable first, so you can refer to it from the [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals):

```
func Function1(n int) int {
    a := 10
    var Function2 func(m int) int

    Function2 = func(m int) int {
        if m <= a {
            return a
        }
        return Function2(m - 1)
    }

    return Function2(n)
}
```

Try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fD6fjED8oN).

Comment: The parameter doesn't need to be named in the declaration so `var Function2 func(int) int` also works and avoids repeating oneself.  Not sure when/if this changed.

Comment: @JamesK This has always been like that, see [Getting method parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377433/getting-method-parameter-names/31377793#31377793). Providing parameter names might still have documentation value.

Comment: TLDR: There is a simple solution -- declare the function before defining it.

Answer (score 11):

```
var Function2 func(m int) int
Function2 = func(m int) int {
    ...
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice