# Golang nested class inside function

Tags: go, nested

Go supports nested struct  inside function but no nested function except lambda, does it mean there is no way to define a nested class inside function?

```
func f() {
    // nested struct Cls inside f
    type Cls struct {
    ...
    }
    // try bounding foo to Cls but fail
    func (c *Cls) foo() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Thus it feels a bit strange that class is weaken inside function.

Any hints?

Comment: `struct` is a struct type. Go doesn't have classes.

Comment: @icza sorry the `class` above means `struct` with bounding function. Forgive my incorrect expression.

Comment: Yes, I understood, I just corrected the term or terminology.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually it doesn't matter if you want to declare the function *with* or *without* a receiver: nesting functions in Go are not allowed.

Although you can use [Function literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) to achieve something like this:

```
func f() {
    foo := func(s string) {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }

    foo("Hello World!")
}
```

Here we created a variable `foo` which has a function type and it is declared inside another function `f`. Calling the "outer" function `f` outputs: `"Hello World!"` as expected.

Try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7BH8C5nJOB).

Comment: ok~ and is there a way to bound a Function literal to the nested `struct`?

Comment: @HayesPan No, you can't. Not in the sense of creating a method for the type. You could specifying an additional parameter to the function literal which would be of the `struct` type like the receiver, but it will not be a part of the `struct`'s method set. A _Function literal_ is not a _function_, it is just a _value_ (which has a function type).

Comment: what if i want to call this literal function recursively from inside itself?

Comment: @schehata Then check out this: [Define a recursive function within a function in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099441/define-a-recursive-function-within-a-function-in-go/28099510#28099510)

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted icza's answer but just to extend it a little, here's his example slightly modified, showing that variables defined in the outer function are visible to the inner function:

```
    func f(s string) {
        foo := func() {
            fmt.Println(s)
        }

        foo()
    }

    func main() {
        f("Hello, World!\n")
    }
```