# Getting method parameter names

Tags: reflection, go

Given the following Go method:

```
func (t *T) TMethod(data *testData) (interface{}, *error) {
    ...
}
```

I want to reflect the name of the parameter (which is `data` here).

I tried the following, but it returns the structure name (which is `testData` here):

```
reflect.ValueOf(T).MethodByName("TMethod").Type.In(0).Elem().Name()
```

How can I get the name of the parameter?

Comment: You didn't try that code, since it doesn't compile.

Comment: @ rightfold: I tried it , just added more details.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no way to get the names of the parameters of a method or a function.

The reason for this is because the names are not really important for someone calling a method or a function. What matters is the types of the parameters and their order.

A [Function type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) denotes the set of all functions with the same parameter and result types. The type of 2 functions having the same parameter and result types is identical regardless of the names of the parameters. The following code prints `true`:

```
func f1(a int) {}
func f2(b int) {}

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(f1) == reflect.TypeOf(f2))
```

It is even possible to create a function or method where you don't even give names to the parameters (within a list of parameters or results, the names must either all be present or all be absent). This is valid code:

```
func NamelessParams(int, string) {
    fmt.Println("NamelessParams called")
}
```

For details and examples, see [Is unnamed arguments a thing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950877/is-unnamed-arguments-a-thing-in-go/40951013#40951013)

If you want to create some kind of framework where you call functions passing values to "named" parameters (e.g. mapping incoming API params to Go function/method params), you may use a [`struct`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) because using the `reflect` package you can get the named fields (e.g. [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) and [`Type.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type)), or you may use a [`map`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types). See this related question: [Initialize function fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153929/initialize-function-fields/48154019#48154019)

Here is a relevant discussion on the [golang-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/nM_ZhL7fuGc).