# Print Missing Values

Tags: arrays, loops, go, conditional-statements

Using Go, I am trying to send values from main to the function. I want to check if any parameter sent to function is empty. If there is any missing values, I want to print that the "***Parameter value***" is empty. If there are multiple parameters empty, I want to print that as well. If all parameters are correctly given, return the value.

```
func FederationValidarator(a string, b string) (string, string) {
    // var Messages []string
    rArray := [2]string{a, b}
    // i :=0
    for i := 0; i < len(rArray); i++ {
        if rArray[i] != "" {
            fmt.Println("Nothing is empty")
        } else {
            // var Messages []string
            fmt.Println("%s is Missing")
        }
    }
    return a, b
}

func main() {
    a, b := FederationValidarator("", "world")
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

**How can i code to print missing values?** I want to get the following output.

The results:

```
%s is Missing
Nothing is empty

world
```

Expected Output:

```
a is Missing
world
```

Comment: Your question is missing a question.

Comment: @zerkms... Thank you for suggestion.... I have updated the question. Please find reference

Comment: `if a == "" { fmt.Println("A is missing" }` ?

Comment: @zerkms ... Yes, That is what i wanted to create.

Comment: @zerkms.. Thank You for your response. I have updated the question and code as well as results that appears and expected output. Can you please look into it. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the parameter names (e.g. `a`), for details, see [Getting method parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377433/getting-method-parameter-names/31377793#31377793).

If you need the parameter names, wrap the parameters into a struct, and you can get the names of the fields. You may use reflection to iterate over the fields, and get their values and their names too.

For example:

```
type Param struct {
    A string
    B string
    C string
}

func CheckValues(p Param) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(p)

    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        name := t.Field(i).Name
        if v.Field(i).IsZero() {
            fmt.Printf("%s is empty\n", name)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s is NOT empty\n", name)
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
p := Param{"", "world", ""}
CheckValues(p)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hgqdOi19yTe)):

```
A is empty
B is NOT empty
C is empty
```

One very nice property of this solution is that **it does not depend on the actual parameter type**. You may pass any struct values to it, and it will continue to work. Also it handles "all" field types, not just strings.

So modify the signature to this:

```
func CheckValues(p interface{})
```

And you may also pass anonymous structs, not just values of defined types:

```
a, b, c, d := "", "world", 0, 3

CheckValues(struct {
    A string
    B string
    C int
    D int
}{a, b, c, d})
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vwdZwlA0JhB)):

```
A is empty
B is NOT empty
C is empty
D is NOT empty
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in order to match the result you expect. But it is not the correct way to check parameter names.

```golang
func FederationValidarator(a string, b string) (string, string) {
    
    rArray := [2]string{a, b}
    
    for i := 0; i < len(rArray); i++ {
        if string(rArray[i]) == "" {
            fmt.Printf("%s is Missing\n", rArray[i]) // %s is empty string, Then nothing will appear.
        } else {                        
           fmt.Println(rArray[i])
        }
    }    
    return a, b
}
 
func main() {
    _, _ = FederationValidarator("", "world")
}
```