# Understanding variable scope in Go

Tags: go, scope, variable-declaration, type-declaration

I am going through the `Go specification` to learn the language, and these points are taken from the spec under [`Declarations and scope`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope).

Though I am able to understand points 1-4, I am confused on points `5` and `6`:

> 5. The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a
>      function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl
>      for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the
>      innermost containing block.
> 6. The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function begins at
>      the identifier in the TypeSpec and ends at the end of the innermost
>      containing block.

This is the code which I used to understand scope in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := 42
    fmt.Println(x)
    {
        fmt.Println(x)
        y := "The test message"
        fmt.Println(y)
    }
    // fmt.Println(y) // outside scope of y
}
```

From this what I understand is `scope of x` is within the `main` function, and the `scope of y` is inside the opening and closing brackets after `fmt.Println(x)`, and I cannot use `y` outside of the closing brackets.

If I understand it correctly, both points `4 and 5` are saying the same thing. So my questions are:

1. If they are saying the same thing, what is the `importance` of both the
   points?
2. If they are different, can you please let me know the `difference`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're making the same point, with the same rules, about two different things: the first is about variables and constants, the second is about type identifiers. So, if you declare a type inside a block, the same scoping rules apply as would apply to a variable declared at the same spot.

Comment: As for the usage of locally scoped types, sometimes it is useful to declare a throwaway type in a lesser scope so you don't have to worry about muddying the namespace.

Comment: Or for use in a locally-declared function. But generally, locally-declared types are a fairly rare occurrence.

Comment: I use them quite a bit in my API when calling some 3rd party API. I declare the response type locally in the function because the response is Unmarshalled, dismantled, and its values are used only inside that function (See https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/). Just my two cents for an example. I should benchmark to see if a local declared type is more/less overhead... probably no difference, but could be an interesting experiment.

Comment: I feel like anonymous types are a more common solution for that use case, but I may well be wrong about that.

Comment: Er sorry, that's what I meant. It's anonymous.

Comment: Good answer, except that it's *almost* the same point with *almost* the same rules made about two different things (as clarified by @icza's answer.)

Answer (score 7):

Besides applying to different things (rule #5 is for [constant-](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations) and [variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations), rule #6 is for [type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)), there is also an important difference in wording:

> 5. The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a
>      function **begins at the end** of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl
>      for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the
>      innermost containing block.
> 6. The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function **begins at
>      the identifier in the TypeSpec** and ends at the end of the innermost
>      containing block.

This is the reason why there are 2 rules and not one.

What does this mean? What does the difference imply?

#### # 5 Variable and Constant declarations (inside a function)

The scope of the declared variables or constants begins at the end of the declaration. This means if you're creating a function variable, initializing it with an anonymous function, it can't refer to itself.

This is invalid:

```
f := func() {
    f()
}
```

Attempting to compile:

```
prog.go:5:3: undefined: f
```

This is because the declaration ends after the closing bracket of the anonymous function, so inside of it you can't call `f()`. A workaround would be:

```
var f func()
f = func() {
    f()
}
```

Now here the declaration of `f` ends at the closing parenthesis (of its type `func()`), so in the next line when we assign an anonymous function to it, it is valid to refer to `f` (to call the function value stored in the `f` variable) because it is now in scope. See related question: [Define a recursive function within a function in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099441/define-a-recursive-function-within-a-function-in-go/28099510#28099510)

Similarly, when initializing a variable e.g. with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), you can't refer to the variable inside of it:

```
var m = map[int]string{
    1:  "one",
    21: "twenty-" + m[1],
}
```

This gives a compile-time error ("undefined: m"), because `m` is not in scope yet inside the composite literal.

And obviously this workaround works:

```
var m = map[int]string{
    1: "one",
}
m[21] = "twenty-" + m[1]
```

#### # 6 Type declarations (inside a function)

The scope of the declared type begins at the identifier in the declaration. So in contrast to rule #5, it is valid to refer to the type itself inside its declaration.

Does it have any advantage / significance?

Yes, you can declare recursive types, such as this:

```
type Node struct {
    Left, Right *Node
}
```

The type identifier `Node` is in scope right after it appears in the type declaration, which ends with the closing bracket, but before that we could refer to it, meaningfully.

Another example would be a slice type whose element type is itself:

```
type Foo []Foo
```

You can read more about it here: [How can a slice contain itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077566/how-can-a-slice-contain-itself)

Yet another valid example:

```
type M map[int]M
```

Comment: That's an important distinction, allowing a type to refer to itself (e.g. a struct containing a pointer to its type) but not allowing a variable or constant declaration to refer to the variable being declared.