# How `type Name *Name` works?

Tags: go, types

I was looking at some examples on golang.org homepage and found `Peano Integers`. This example defines the type `Number` like this:

```
type Number *Number
```

First time looking at this code I thought it should not compile, I think  I haven't understood how type works in Go.

Can you explain how Go is defining type `Number` here? This looks very confusing to me.

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GXMRxO8cwGB)

```golang
// Peano integers are represented by a linked
// list whose nodes contain no data
// (the nodes are the data).
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms

// This program demonstrates that Go's automatic
// stack management can handle heavily recursive
// computations.

package main

import "fmt"

// Number is a pointer to a Number
type Number *Number

// The arithmetic value of a Number is the
// count of the nodes comprising the list.
// (See the count function below.)

// -------------------------------------
// Peano primitives

func zero() *Number {
    return nil
}

func isZero(x *Number) bool {
    return x == nil
}

func add1(x *Number) *Number {
    e := new(Number)
    *e = x
    return e
}

func sub1(x *Number) *Number {
    return *x
}

func add(x, y *Number) *Number {
    if isZero(y) {
        return x
    }
    return add(add1(x), sub1(y))
}

func mul(x, y *Number) *Number {
    if isZero(x) || isZero(y) {
        return zero()
    }
    return add(mul(x, sub1(y)), x)
}

func fact(n *Number) *Number {
    if isZero(n) {
        return add1(zero())
    }
    return mul(fact(sub1(n)), n)
}

// -------------------------------------
// Helpers to generate/count Peano integers

func gen(n int) *Number {
    if n > 0 {
        return add1(gen(n - 1))
    }
    return zero()
}

func count(x *Number) int {
    if isZero(x) {
        return 0
    }
    return count(sub1(x)) + 1
}

// -------------------------------------
// Print i! for i in [0,9]

func main() {
    for i := 0; i <= 9; i++ {
        f := count(fact(gen(i)))
        fmt.Println(i, "! =", f)
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't clear? You understand `type MyInt *int`. The same goes for `type Number *Number`. What may be surprising is that the type identifier is in score right after its name in the declaration, so it can be used to create recursive data structures. See related: [Understanding variable scope in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503560/understanding-variable-scope-in-go/52506086#52506086).

Comment: thanks, now I understand it. I will read golang specs further