# Where is explained the scope of variables in Go in official documentation?

Tags: go, scope

I can't find any place in [go.dev](https://go.dev/doc/) where private/global variables and the scope of variables are explained.

As a related problem, I was struggling trying to import a variable from a `_test.go` file. Of course this is not in that documentation, but I think is related to the compiler?

Comment: It's in the [Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec).

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding variable scope in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503560/understanding-variable-scope-in-go)

Comment: I was struggling trying to import a variable from a `_test.go` file.
Of course this is not in that documentation, but I think is related to the compiler?

Comment: `_test.go` files are ignored by the go tool unless you're running tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declarations and scope are detailed in different parts of the [Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec), for details and comprehensive overview, see [Understanding variable scope in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503560/understanding-variable-scope-in-go/52506086#52506086).

As you mentioned in the comments, your problem is that you can't import variables from `_test.go` files. The language spec doesn't mention this, so this is an implementation restriction.

Quoting from [Command documentation: Compile packages and dependencies](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies):

> When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'.

They are only used when you run tests. [Test packages:](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages)

> 'Go test' recompiles each package along with any files with names matching the file pattern "*_test.go". These additional files can contain test functions, benchmark functions, and example functions. See 'go help testfunc' for more. Each listed package causes the execution of a separate test binary. Files whose names begin with "_" (including "_test.go") or "." are ignored.
>
> Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.

Comment: Thanks @icza, excellent help as always!