# Can an anonymous struct have methods in Go？

Tags: go, variables, methods, struct, composite-literals

```
var anonymousStruct = &struct {
    Value int
    Test  func()
}{
    Test: func() {
        fmt.Println(anonymousStruct.Value)
    },
}
```

Looking at the code, I encountered an issue on line 6: the function "Test" cannot access the parameter "Value". Is there a way for the function to access "Value" without passing it as a parameter again, similar to "anonymousStruct.Test(anonymousStruct.Value)"? In other words, can an anonymous struct have methods instead of functions in Go? Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Hope it helps [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mbt9QyNA9uo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare methods to anonymous struct as a [method declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_declarations) can only contain a named type (as the receiver).

Besides that, anonymous structs can have methods if they embed types that have methods (they get promoted).

In your example you cannot refer to the `anonymousStruct` variable in the [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals), because the variable will be in scope only after the declaration (after the composite literal). See [Spec: Declarations and scope](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope); example: [Define a recursive function within a function in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099441/define-a-recursive-function-within-a-function-in-go/28099510#28099510).

So for example you may initialize the function field after the variable declaration:

```
var anonymousStruct = &struct {
    Value int
    Test  func()
}{Value: 3}

anonymousStruct.Test = func() {
    fmt.Println(anonymousStruct.Value)
}

anonymousStruct.Test()
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZCpN3c1YQvK)):

```
3
```